# which oracle .jar file to use with AWS toolkit for eclipse?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does anyone know which Oracle .jar file is the appropriate one to use to connect to an AWS Oracle RDS from AWS Toolkit for Eclipse? (Current version is the latest & greatest on AWS: 11.2.0.2.v5)

Thanks,
Debbie[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You just use whatever [download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) supports the features you are using.